# How to specify index in Entity Framework 5.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-5

I have a select statement where it returns thousands of records. i want to use Index hints with the query. How do i do this using Entity Framework

```
 var actCosts = db.ActCosts.Where(t => t.ScenarioID == scenarioID).ToList();
```

like this

```
select * from ActCost WITH(INDEX(IX_ActCost_ScenarioID)) where ScenarioID = 797
```

Comment: You can't add query hints using Linq. If you want to add these you are going to have to execute actual SQL.

Comment: I think in such scenario one should use Store procedure.Or fetch less record using Skip Take in List .Am I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of adding query hints to the current version of Entity Framework; however, they are considering implementing it in a future release.

See the proposal at https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/261 as well as some possible work-arounds.